# How to run sysprep without creating admin account?

Tags: windows, sysprep

I have installed Windows 10 Home version and updated it to Enterprise and added the KMS server. If I now run the sysprep everything else is ok but sysprep adds an account admin. How can I prevent this or delete the admin account before a user will start the OOBE process?

Password for account admin is "admim".

Comment: In principle you do that by invoking a certain key stroke (Shift+F10 if I am not mistaken) *during installation*. Then it allows to proceed without OOBE consent and and without creating any accounts. Check Microsoft manual about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the local "Administrator" account it cannot be removed. It can only be enabled or disabled.

For example if you are in audit mode for sysprep, its enabled and uses that account to log you on so you can make changes to the machine in audit mode.

CTRL+SHIFT+F3 will allow you to enter audit mode and make changes to the machine, without creating an account.

Read more here about audit mode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-windows-to-audit-mode-or-oobe?view=windows-11

Answer (score 0):

Audit mode will enable the local admin account but I managed to disabled it

1. Press CTRL+SHIFT+F3 to get audit mode
2. Install software
3. Run C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /shutdown
4. Start computer and when you see the language selection press SHIFT+F10 to open command promtp.
5. Disable admin account. I removed it from settings (press WIN+I to open settings)
6. Run C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /shutdown